# Background-color of tr only appears behind text

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have a table in a page generated by an MVC 3 web application.  I am attempting to highlight a particular row by setting a background-color for the tr tag.  When I do this the background-color only appears around the actual text, and not the whitespace between the cells.  How can I make it cover the whitespace between the cells?  There are no borders for the cells.
Here is some code, @schedule.classString resolves to ActiveSet for the entry I want highlighted.

```
<style>
    .ActiveSet
    {
        background-color:#b4c2e3;
    }
</style>

@foreach (var schedule in device.Schedules)
                    {
                        <tr class="@schedule.classString">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table{
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

This will delete spaces between cell's borders, so you wiln't have this white space as well.

Comment: Thanks!  Always goot to know there are css properties out there that I still don't know!

Comment: If unswer helped, it's good practice to accept it by pressing check sign under the rating. This is improve both your accept rating and rating points of the unswer and the asker.

Comment: I did so as soon as the 15 minute wait period expired.  Got to give credit where credit is due :)